# Manga where a guy and girl play a videogame where they discover that the people in the game are sentient

Tags: story-identification, manga

The guy and the girl are classmates and the meet up to play the videogame. They then discover that the game is kind of alive and the one of the characters can hear them. They end up trying to manage the game as gods of some sort and give blessings to characters etc...

Edit: I believe it was black and white and the main characters had dark hair. One of the main characters inside the game is a blonde haired prince I think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this ***[Endo and Kobayashi Live! The Latest on Tsundere Villainess Lieselotte](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/endo-and-kobayashi-live-the-latest-on-tsundere-villainess-lieselotte)***...?

> One day, Crown Prince Sieg hears the Voices of the Gods out of the blue. Apparently, his fiancée Lieselotte is a “tsun de rais” villainess destined to meet her demise...and her sharp tongue is just a way of covering up her embarrassment. The prince can hardly contain himself after discovering Lieselotte's adorable hidden side. Little does he know, the heavenly beings that bestowed this knowledge unto him are actually high schoolers! Can he use their divine prophecy (let’s play commentary) to save his betrothed and avoid a Bad End?!

A Japanese school girl is into a romance simulation game involving a blond prince and his villainess fiancée, and ropes one of her male classmates into playing the game and providing a vocal commentary on the game alongside her.

At one point, the prince hears the voices of the students coming from the sky, and mistakes them for gods. When the students realise the prince can hear them, they decide to guide him through the game to help his fiancée avoid a bad ending.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This Is It! Thank you!